# Second HTTP call to the same trivial method is way slower

Tags: node.js, performance, fibonacci

The code is pretty simple:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/fibonacci/:num', (req,res) => {
    fibonacci(req.params.num).then( (n) => {
        res.json({num: n})
    })
})

function fibo(n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibo(n - 2) + fibo(n - 1);
}

const fibonacci = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve(fibo(num))
    })
}

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${8080}.`)
})
```

The first call to http://localhost:8080/fibonacci/40 needs circa 1600 ms to complete.

Starting from second call, the request need almost 4600 ms to complete.

In the following case instead, for first and the second request the time spent is the same.

```
app.get('/dostuff/:num', (req,res) => {
        res.json({num: doStuff(req.params.num)})
    })

function doStuff(n){
    for(let i=0; i<n*10000; i++) { i=i}
}
```

Why?

Comment: I ran your code with Nodejs 12.16.1 and I see something similar: 1100ms for first call, 2800ms for subsequent calls. (Using the value of '40'). Interesting.

Comment: And what are timings w/o Promise wrapping?

Comment: No changes at all without promises.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason that the second call takes longer is because the first call is still running in the background!

Because your function is recursive, `fibo(40)` results in 330 million calls to `fibo()`!

To demonstrate this, I modified the code to track an iterator `i`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let i;

app.get('/fibonacci/:num', (req,res) => {
    i = 0;
    fibonacci(req.params.num).then( (n) => {
        console.log(i);
        res.json({num: n})
    });
});

function fibo(n) {
    i++;
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibo(n - 2) + fibo(n - 1);
}

const fibonacci = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        resolve(fibo(num));
    });
}

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${8080}.`)
});
```

A request to `/fibonacci/40` results in `331160281` being logged.

I must admit though, I don't understand enough about how the Node engine works to explain how it arrives at the answer within a couple of seconds. I presume this is to do with how V8 consolidates the code. Perhaps someone can explain this?

Comment: How can It run in the background but returning the correct result ? And why the First call Is so fast ? This do not answer my question.. :(

Comment: It's because you as the programmer are asking for 330 million function calls to happen, but the engine realises it doesn't need to do all of them to resolve the answer to your promise :-) I'll do a bit more work and edit my answer to show how this may be true. I still not be able to explain every element of the algorithmic efficiency though. I'm not clever enough for that!

Comment: And it realises this thing only the first time? and the secods doesn't ? NAH !